# Angular $http read String?

Tags: angularjs, ajax

The back end guy wants to send me a string, which will be returned by `$http.post`. If he sends me something like "`success`", I will get error like "parsing Json failed". I want him to wrap the string into object like "`{"message": "success"}`", which works fine. But other back end guys say that front end should comply with back end, so they will just send me the string. Is there any way that I can read the string?

This is the code I use if he sends me "`{"message": "success"}`", which works perfectly:

```
AdminService.saveCache(cache)
    .then(function(data) {
        var data = data.data;

        if (data.message == "success") {
            scope.successMessage = "Cache hours saved successfully";
        } else {
            scope.errorMessage = data.message;
        }
    }, function() {
        scope.errorMessage = "Submission failed";
    });
```

Comment: AFAIK, Angular only parses the returned string as JSON if the response content type is application/json. And "success" is not valid JSON. So, if that's indeed the case, you can tell the guy that the response it sends is incorrect. He should set the content type to text/plain.

Comment: Are they returning 200 OK responses no matter what?  It seems to me that returning 4xx responses for invalid requests is better.  Then `$http` can properly resolve/reject the promise appropriately.

Comment: Moreover, if there is an error, the guy shouldn't send back a response with a status 200 (which means success). The status should be 4xx or 5xx.

Comment: @JBNizet They don't know about front end. I tried to explain that. They just don't understand. That's why they send me error message when there is an error.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, if they get something error in back end, they still send me 200 OK with error message.

Comment: Point them to wikepedia link (or W3C spec)  for `http status codes` then

Comment: You don't need to know about frontend to comply to the basic HTTP rules: 200 means success, and a response with content type application/json should contain valid JSON.

Comment: @charlietfl I gave them a lot of links, they just let me talk to another senior front end developer to get an answer. :(

Comment: so what is contentType header being sent? Can configure the request for different `dataType` and throw an error yourself to end up in catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default angular tries to detect if a http response contains JSON. Sometimes this detection fails and you get such an error as you described in your question.

You can avoid this behavior for a single request if you override the response transformation by providing an `transformResponse` property for on the configuration object passed to the request:

```
$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'POST',
  //Just return original response from server without parsing
  transformResponse: [function (data, headers) {
        return data;
    }];
});
```

Alternatively you can change the default behavior for all your app's http requests by overriding the default response transformation:

```
myApp.config('$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse = [function (data, headers) {
        return data;
    }];
}]);
```

For more information see [API Reference $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) section "Transforming Requests and Responses"

Answer (score 0):

the API Response Content-Type should be set to text/plain; and use POSTMAN to verify, it would save you a lot of headache